# WPF: Dropdown of a Combobox highlightes the text

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When I type in the combobox I automatically opens enables the dropdown list

```
searchComboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
```

The problem here is - the text gets highlighted and the next keystrock overwrites the previous text.

How can I disable the text highlighting when ComboBox DropDown opens up?

Comment: Which "ComboBox DropDown" are you talking about?

Comment: Did you set false to IsTextSearchEnabled property of the comboBox ?? It will disable selection of the text.
hope that will help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better late than never and if some one else hit this proplem he might use this.

There is away todo this if you override combobox.
First get handle on the textbox that is used in the template and register to selectionchanged event.

```
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
  base.OnApplyTemplate();

  var element = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");
  if (element != null)
  {
    var textBox = (TextBox)element;
    textBox.SelectionChanged += OnDropSelectionChanged;
  }
}

private void OnDropSelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Your code
}
```

Then in the event handler you can set the selection again like you want it to be. In my case I was calling IsDropDownOpen in code. Saved selection there then put it back in the event handler. Ugly but did the trick.

Comment: Please Can you write out the complete code I have the exact same problem but am new at this so please expound. My element is not a textbox but a combobox.

Comment: Can you please post an sample code in textbox_SelectionChanged? is it like this? TextBox tb = (TextBox)e.Source;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                tb.SelectionStart = 0;
            }

Answer (score 9):

I had this very same issue and like some of the users being new to WPF, struggled to get the solution given by Einar Guðsteinsson to work. So in support of his answer I'm pasting here the steps to get this to work. (Or more accurately how I got this to work).

First create a custom combobox class which inherits from the Combobox class. See code below for full implementation. You can change the code in OnDropSelectionChanged to suit your individual requirements.

namespace MyCustomComboBoxApp
{
using System.Windows.Controls;

```
public class MyCustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private int caretPosition;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var element = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");
        if (element != null)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)element;
            textBox.SelectionChanged += OnDropSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnDropSelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;
        
        if (base.IsDropDownOpen && txt.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            caretPosition = txt.SelectionLength; // caretPosition must be set to TextBox's SelectionLength
            txt.CaretIndex = caretPosition;
        }
        if (txt.SelectionLength == 0 && txt.CaretIndex != 0)
        {
            caretPosition = txt.CaretIndex;
        }
    }

}
```

Ensure that this custom combo class exists in the same project. THen you can use the code below to reference this combo in your UI.

```
<Window x:Class="MyCustomComboBoxApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:cc="clr-namespace:MyCustomComboBoxApp"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=cb}">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <cc:MyCustomComboBox x:Name="cb" IsEditable="True" Height="20" Margin="10" IsTextSearchEnabled="False" KeyUp="cb_KeyUp">
            <ComboBoxItem>Toyota</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Honda</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Suzuki</ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem>Vauxhall</ComboBoxItem>
        </cc:MyCustomComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Thats it! Any questions, please ask! I'll do my best to help.

THanks to Einar Guðsteinsson for his solution!

Comment: On enhancment from my side: caretPosition must be set to TextBox's SelectionLength

Answer (score 4):

Further to clsturgeon's answer, I have solved the issue by setting the selection when DropDownOpened event occurred:

```
private void ItemCBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)((ComboBox)sender).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (ComboBox)sender);
    textBox.SelectionStart = ((ComboBox)sender).Text.Length;
    textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Comment: It works, the shortest solution I've found, thank you :D

Comment: This does not work if the caret is not at the end of the text.

Answer (score 3):

I think in the Solution provided by Andrew N there is something missing as when I tried it out the Selection Changed event of the TextBox was placing the caret at the wrong place. So I made this change to solve that.

```
namespace MyCustomComboBoxApp { using System.Windows.Controls;

public class MyCustomComboBox : ComboBox
{
    private int caretPosition;

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        var element = GetTemplateChild("PART_EditableTextBox");
        if (element != null)
        {
            var textBox = (TextBox)element;
            textBox.SelectionChanged += OnDropSelectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void OnDropSelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox txt = (TextBox)sender;

        if (base.IsDropDownOpen && txt.SelectionLength > 0)
        {
            caretPosition = txt.SelectionLength; // caretPosition must be set to TextBox's SelectionLength
            txt.CaretIndex = caretPosition;
        }
        if (txt.SelectionLength == 0 && txt.CaretIndex != 0)
        {
            caretPosition = txt.CaretIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great spot and fix Mohammed!

Comment: The second if statement does nothing apart from setting the caretPosition variable that is not used.  Remove it, the variable and then in the first if statement assign in one line - txt.CaretIndex = txt.SelectionLength

Answer (score 0):

When a comboxbox gains focus you can disable the text highlighting (i.e. by selecting no text upon the GotFocus event).  However, when you pulldown the combobox the system is going to locate the item in the list and make that the selected item.  This in turn automatically highlights the text.  If I understand the behaviour you are looking for, I do not believe it is fully possible.

Comment: you are right ? it seems not possible even if I use IsTextSearchEnabled property to false as mentioned by asim.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it using a modified answer from Jun Xie. Assuming you are using the `keyUp` event for your combobox search, I found an edge case in my custom use case that would still overwrite the text:

- Type in the combobox for the first time. Text is fine.
- Use up and down arrow keys to select an item in the list, but not "committing" the change (pressing enter, for example, and closing the dropDown selections. Note the text is highlighted at this point like clsturgeon points out.
- Try to type in the textbox again. In this case the text will be over-ridden because the dropdown was still open hence the event never fired to clear the highlight.

The solution is to check if an item is selected. Here's the working code:
XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SearchBox" IsEditable="True" KeyUp="SearchBox_KeyUp" 
          PreviewMouseDown="SearchBox_PreviewMouseDown" IsTextSearchEnabled="False"
          DropDownOpened="SearchBox_DropDownOpened">
</ComboBox>
```

Code:

```
private void SearchBox_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    SearchBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
    if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
    {
        e.Handled = true;

        //if trying to navigate but there's noting selected, then select one
        if(SearchBox.Items.Count > 0 && SearchBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
        {
            SearchBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }
    }
    else if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        //commit to selection
    }
    else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SearchBox.Text))
    {
        SearchBox.Items.Clear();
        SearchBox.IsDropDownOpen = false;
        SearchBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else if (SearchBox.Text.Length > 1)
    {
        //if something is currently selected, then changing the selected index later will loose
        //focus on textbox part of combobox and cause the text to
        //highlight in the middle of typing. this will "eat" the first letter or two of the user's search
        if(SearchBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            TextBox textBox = (TextBox)((ComboBox)sender).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (ComboBox)sender);
            //backup what the user was typing
            string temp = SearchBox.Text;
            //set the selected index to nothing. sets focus to dropdown
            SearchBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //restore the text. sets focus and highlights the combobox text
            SearchBox.Text = temp;
            //set the selection to the end (remove selection)
            textBox.SelectionStart = ((ComboBox)sender).Text.Length;
            textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
        }

        //your search logic
    }
}

private void SearchBox_DropDownOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)((ComboBox)sender).Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", (ComboBox)sender);
    textBox.SelectionStart = ((ComboBox)sender).Text.Length;
    textBox.SelectionLength = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative.  Prevent the framework from messing with selection.

```
public class ReflectionPreventSelectAllOnDropDown
{
    private static readonly PropertyInfo edtbPropertyInfo;
    static ReflectionPreventSelectAllOnDropDown()
    {
        edtbPropertyInfo = typeof(ComboBox).GetProperty("EditableTextBoxSite", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    }
    public void DropDown(ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        if (!comboBox.IsDropDownOpen)
        {
            var edtb = edtbPropertyInfo.GetValue(comboBox);
            edtbPropertyInfo.SetValue(comboBox, null);
            comboBox.IsDropDownOpen = true;
            edtbPropertyInfo.SetValue(comboBox, edtb);
        }
    }
    
}
```